# Moving "Dynamic Worksheets" between CRM Online environments

Tags: excel, dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm-online

My understanding of how this works and the reality appear to be different.

### Goal

Export a Dynamic Worksheet from one CRM Online tenant. Upload it as an "Existing Report" in a solution. Export the *solution* to another tenant. Similar to SSRS reports, I expect the datasource to be updated to the new tenant. I then want to open the Dynamic Worksheet via Reports in the new tenant and see the data in Excel coming from that second tenant.

### Environment

I am using CRM Online (now with UR12) and Excel 2013. I am able to replicate this on another machine with Excel 2007.

### Walk-through

I have a Dynamic Worksheet that I have exported from a CRM Online tenant ("T1"). I did this by creating an Advanced Find, viewing the results then clicking Export to Excel. I then chose the "Dynamic Worksheet" option and saved the resulting `.xml` file. If I open the file locally (and accept all the usual security warnings), I see data from T1 in the worksheet.

I then created a new solution in T1, called "My Report". From the solution, I went to Reports, Add New and added an "Existing Report" by browsing to my newly saved `.xml` file.

I then exported my solution as unmanaged (not that it matters).

Next I signed out of T1 and signed into to another CRM Online tenant ("T2") and imported the solution. I can then see my new report under Reports in T2. If I click the report, I am prompted to download the spreadsheet. If I open the downloaded spreadsheet (and agree to the security warnings etc as before) I do not see any data. If I click `Refresh from CRM` then nothing appears to happen. If I click on `Data > Connections > Refresh All` then the content in my spreadsheet changes to:

> Microsoft Online Services requires JavaScript to sign in. This web
>   browser either does not support JavaScript, or scripts are being
>   blocked.
>
> To find out whether your browser supports JavaScript, or to allow
>   scripts, see the browser's online help.

### My Theory

It seems like, not unreasonably, the target datasource is being stored in the worksheet (I can see this by viewing the XML and I see the path of my "T1" tenant). I expected that this would be changed during the solution import phase but it isn't. If I change the XML manually, it will look at my T2 environment and work as expected.

I had hoped that one of the following options would cause Excel to look to the right place:

- I have the Outlook client installed and configured. T1 and T2 are both configured as organisations that I can connect to. I hoped this might cause Excel to prompt to connect to one of the two environments.
- I reconfigured Outlook client to only connect to T2 (deleted T1 from config) but seemingly had impact on where Excel connects to
- I signed into T2 via my default browser (IE9) and opened the worksheet but again this did not effect a change.

It will be no surprise that this example simplifies a more complex case (a workbook with many linked worksheets such as the one above). The workbook is part of a solution which is being deployed between DEV and UAT environments. Manually frigging the XML each time I export the solution is not a scalable option.

### Question(s)

- Is this behaviour expected or yet another post-UR12 / post-O365 bug?
- What haven't I tried that might allow this to "just work"?

Comment: +1 for the insight on the difference between own understanding and and this cumbersome thing called reality. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not at all surprised to report that Microsoft have confirmed this behaviour to be *by design*. I can't say that I find it logical, given the behaviour of SSRS reports uploaded via a solution. Nor can I say that the development experience is good, given that I may invest some time in developing my reports against a DEV environment but I cannot natively import that investment to another tenant via a solution. I must cede, however that it is understandable.

If you're interested in my current workaround solution then follow these steps. I am also poised to try and develop a supported, CRM-based solution. If you favourite this post then I'll update it when I have finished the required code.

Workaround:

1. Save spreadsheet as an XML Worksheet
2. Open the XML file in your favourite XML editor
3. Use Find and Replace to change your original tenant URL to your new tenant URL
4. Save and Close

Fairly easy, but a bit too *hands-on* for my liking...